# ORACLE convert NVARCHAR2 to Date/Time

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to convert column `VER_TIME NVARCHAR2(30)` in Oracle database.

Sample Date = `2014-08-27 12:20:24`

Required result = `08/27/2014 12:20:24`

I have tried `TO_DATE(VER_TIME)` but get the following error "literal does not match format string"

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to specify the date format used for the conversion, for the sample date given, the call should be :

```
TO_DATE('2014-08-27 12:20:24', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS')
```

[TO_DATE Documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)